# Calculating amount of permutations

Tags: algorithm, permutation, wolframalpha

Given a certain random number I would like to know how many distinct permutations are possible of that number.
For small numbers I can work it out by hand but I can't seem to extract a general algorithm for it.

So I asked wolfram alpha what are the [permutations of {a,a,a,b, b, c, d}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=permutations+of+%7Ba,a,a,b,+b,+c,+d%7D)
and it returned 420.
The accompanying code link said it was calculated using:

```
Length[{a, a, a, b, b, c, d}]!/Times @@ (#1! & ) /@ Tally[{a, a, a, b, b, c, d}][[All,2]]
```

Can anyone explain this code or explain how I should go about calculating the possible number of permutations of a certain random number.

Note: I don't need to know what the different permutations are. I just want to calculate how many distinct are possible.

Comment: Have a look at `multinomial`.

Comment: Thanks @beaker, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_unique_permutations_of_words should suffice. If I understand it better and have a working (c++) code sample I'll post it here as an answer.